# Is there a way to make a google colab notebook which multiple people can use?

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

im trying to make a colab notebook on which all my teammates can work.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive/')

df = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/Doceree-HCP_Train.csv",encoding='latin1')
print(df)
```

we are trying to use this method but it doesn't work on everyone's system.

i also directly imported the dataset onto the colab files and copied the past from there as

```
df=pd.read_csv("path")
```

is there a way to connect this to a shared google drive and import the dataset from there and make it work on everyone's system.

Comment: What do you mean by work on everyone's system? Do you mean that each individual can access and run the notebook one at a time?  Or do you mean all team members can simultaneously work on same notebook?  Additionally, what does the ```pd.read_csv ``` have to do with a notebook?

Comment: @itprorh66 we cant work on it simultaneously since one needs to reload the page to see updates on it. i want us to work on it one at a time. and `pd.read_csv` was written just to show different methods we've used to import the file.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Open ended and opinion based questions that boil down to subjective responses are generally not a good fit for this site, since there generally is not a single correct answer but a range of opinions based on different approaches.